# Foreign Key Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I using Entity Data Model Tools, when i create Foreign Key between 2 entity, i do not find the update option (cascase, no action).

Comment: What version of Entity Framework, how are you creating your model (Code first, model first, database first etc)? How are you creating your foreign keys? As Associations? With foreign key option?

Comment: I using version 4, model first. Use Associations to link 2 entity.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need an update option you can perform the same with `addobject(object)`
on context `savachanges` it will take care of it.